# running a script with sudo failing for ssh command & query Mysql database

Tags: mysql, bash, scripting

I have multiple sudo commands in my bash script. So i prefer to run the script as `sudo ./script.sh`
But the below query where I am executing some db command on a remote server by doing ssh is failing if i run the script as sudo ( my guess because it needs to run as root)

I tried to remove sudo from the below command &  ran script as sudo - that fails too. Only way its working is all command with sudo explicitely and run the script as `./script.sh`

```
status=$(ssh -o "UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null" -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" $connect_host 'sudo connect_string mysql -S /var/mysql/state/mysql.sock -uroot mydb -BN -e "update table1 set column1='\'NULL\'' where column2='\'$myvar\''"')
```

Is there any other way to accomplish this?

- **Case 1**

when i run script as sudo and the particular query **with** sudo is like below

```
sudo ./script.sh

status=$(ssh -o "UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null" -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" $connect_host 'sudo connect_string mysql -S /var/mysql/state/mysql.sock -uroot mydb -BN -e "update table1 set column1='\'NULL\'' where column2='\'$myvar\''"')
```

error:

```
Warning: Permanently added '10.0.0.1' () to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

- **Case 2**

when i run script as sudo and the particular query **without** sudo is like below

```
sudo ./script.sh

status=$(ssh -o "UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null" -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" $connect_host 'connect_string mysql -S /var/mysql/state/mysql.sock -uroot mydb -BN -e "update table1 set column1='\'NULL\'' where column2='\'$myvar\''"')
```

error:

```
Warning: Permanently added '10.0.0.1' () to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

- **Case 3**

when i run script **without** sudo and the particular query **with** sudo and all query inside script explicitly mentioning sudo is like below

```
./script.sh

status=$(ssh -o "UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null" -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" $connect_host 'sudo connect_string mysql -S /var/mysql/state/mysql.sock -uroot mydb -BN -e "update table1 set column1='\'NULL\'' where column2='\'$myvar\''"')
```

Runs perfect

Comment: You don't show us how it fails - please attach the errors (add -v to the ssh command too) ..  Suspect your user doesn't have sudo permission on the connect_host.  If you run `script.sh` via sudo the user SSH connects as is possibly different - root@ rather than you@...

Comment: "Fails" as in...a specific error? Those details matter. Normally you should not need `sudo` to run the `mysql` shell, that authentication mechanism is user-independent.

Comment: Added all the error scenarios

Answer (score 0):

The issue in cases 1 and 2 stems from the call of the script via `sudo`. As per `sudo`'s [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo), running `sudo ./myscript.sh` will execute the entire script as `root` on the local machine.

The `ssh` command defaults to the current user, now the `root` user due to the `sudo`  call, and you don't have sufficient authentication to SSH directly as `root` on the external machine.

Running the script as `root` does not modify the SQL command being run on the external machine, so you will need to be explicit with the inclusion of `sudo` ahead of your SQL query.

You have two options:

1. Explicitly use `sudo` in each command that requires it within the script. This is preferred, as this minimises the number of commands that are run as the `root` user.
2. Continue calling the script via `sudo`, but specify your regular use in your `ssh` command. This could be accomplished with either the `-l` option (`ssh -l myuser $connect_host`), or with the `myuser@$connect_host` syntax<sup>[2](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh)</sup>.